# Historical origins of the Čech complex

Tags: reference-request, math-history, simplicial-complex

I am having a surprisingly difficult time finding the original publication that used what is now called the [Čech complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_complex), named after [Eduard Čech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_%C4%8Cech).

The Čech complex is well-known to be the nerve of the union of balls centered at each point in a metric space.

According to this [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+methods), the idea for a simplicial complex determined by the nerve of a covering was independently investigated by Čech and Alexandrov in the 1920s, but it doesn't give any sources.

Does anyone know more about the history of the development of the Čech complex, including the original paper that used it (albeit perhaps not by name)? When was it first referred to as the Čech complex?

**Edit.** After some digging, I found a list of all his publications [here](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/402642/SingleBooks_37-1968-1_5.pdf). However, I'm not sure what title I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: I doubt that the specific "Čech complex" you are asking about is due to Čech.  It is instead named after him because of its connections to Čech cohomology, which he did invent.

Comment: Dieudonné's *A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology 1900-1960* seems to indicate that the notion of the nerve of a covering was first introduced by Alexandrov in the 1926 paper "Über kombinatorische Eigenschaften allgemeiner Kurven".  Čech's contribution was not the idea of taking the nerve of a cover but the idea of taking a limit over *all* open covers.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see. That makes sense. I still hope to track down the first use of the terminology "Čech complex" in the context of the Wikipedia article I linked to, though it may be harder than I think.